# My project work in Visual Studio but won't work after installing on the system

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2015, setup-project, setup-deployment

I've a Project which works when I run it on Visual Studio but won't work after I install it on the system. I'm using Setup File for installation on Windows 7 x64.

I'm using codedom to build an Assembly File. My project after installing works good with the start functions but won't generate the file and when I run the same exact project in visual studio it generated the file.

Comment: There are many reasons why this may not work, it may be a problem with a wrongly installed Dll, an error due to a debug version instead of a release version, a firewall,.... Please be more precise

Comment: @ErosGuil Actually I'm using codedom to build an Assembly File. My project after installing works good with the start functions but won't generate the file and when I run the same exact project in visual studio it generated the file.

Comment: Wild guess: your app doesn't have permissions to write that file? You will need to add logging to your app and inspect the generated logfile to pinpoint the issue

Comment: Actually when I run the build the code in Visual Studio the project works fine but I generated a Setup file and installed it on the same system and it isn't working.

Comment: Please add an answer about your workaround here, and then [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) to help improve this ticket.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! @SaraLiu-MSFT

Comment: Thank you @double-beep

Comment: "won't generate the file " -- we need much more detail in order to help you. If you were helping me, what would you want to know about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a Resources Folder in my Solution Explorer but not in the Application Folder as the Project had a reference of a resource file while building the `.exe` file.